# Json.encode special symbols \u003c MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, escaping

I have JavaScript application, where I use client-side templates (underscore.js, Backbone.js).

Data for initial page load is strapped into the page like this (.cshtml Razor-file):

```
<div id="model">@Json.Encode(Model)</div>
```

Razor engine performs escaping, so, if the `Model` is

```
new { Title = "<script>alert('XSS');</script>" }
```

, in output we have:

```
<div id="model">{&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u0027XSS\u0027)\u003c/script\u003e&quot;}</div>
```

Which after "parse" operation:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#model").html());
```

we have object data with `"Title"` field exactly `"<script>alert('XSS');</script>"`!

When this goes to underscore template, it alerts.

Somehow `\u003c-`like symbols are treated like proper "`<`" symbols.

How do I escape "`<`" symbols to `&lt;` and `&gt;` from DB (if they somehow got there)?

Maybe I can tune `Json.Encode` serialization for escaping these symbols?
Maybe I can set up `Entity Framework` which I`m using, for automatically escape these symbols absolutely all the time when getting data from DB?

Comment: If you disable the `<script>` that parses it as JSON, does it still show an alert?

Comment: It alerts only when is being inserted into DOM thru Underscore template (jQuery-like template). When it is just first on a page in a div, it doesn`t alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\u003c and similar codes are perfectly valid for JS. You can obfuscate whole JS files using this syntax, if you so choose. Essentially, you're seeing an escape character \, u for unicode, and then a 4-character Hex code which relates to a symbol.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blunicode.htm

\u003c - as you've noted, is the < character.

One approach to "fixing" this on the MVC side would be to write a RegEx which looks for the pattern \u - and then captures the next 4 characters. You could then un-encode them into actual unicode characters - and run the resultant text through your XSS prevention algorithms.

As you've noted in your question - just looking for "<" doesn't help. You also can't just look for "\u003cscript" - because this assumes the potential hacker hasn't simply unicode-encoded the entire "script" tag word. The safer approach is to un-escape all of these kinds of codes and then cleanse your HTML in plain-text.

Incidentally, it might make you feel better to note that this is one of the common (and thusfar poorly resolved) issues in XSS prevention. So you aren't alone in wanting a better solution...

You might check out the following libraries to assist in the actual html cleansing:

http://wpl.codeplex.com/ (Microsoft's attempt at a solution - though very bad user feedback)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project_.NET (A private project which is designed to do a lot of this kind of prevention. I find it hard to use, and poorly implemented in .NET)

Both are good references, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your string as HTML before providing it to Underscore.

["HTML escaping in Underscore.js templates"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTnEO8xElDpcJ%3awww.shesek.info/javascript/html-escaping-in-underscore-js-templates+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) explains how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is one of the ways. But it needs to remember to use this every every single time on a client in every template. I was looking for some way to do this on a server, maybe somehow configuring serialization `(@Json.Encode(Model))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write unencoded content you will need to use the [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

Edit:

I guess, perhaps I'm not understanding what your problem is. For example within a test controller I have the following

```
ViewBag.Test = new { Title = "<script>alert('XSS');</script>" };
```

In the related view:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Test));
        console.log(test.Title);
        document.write(test.Title);
    </script>
```

Which in turn outputs to the console:

```
<script>alert('XSS');</script>
```

And opens the alert.

Comment: No, actually I DO want to write encoded content. I want to encode symbols like "<" from DB to avoid script running. Problem is, RAZOR-encoding-mechanism doesn`t help here, when Html.Raw used, we get this:    {"Title":"\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u0027XSS\u0027)\u003c/script\u003e"}

Comment: There are still \u003c symbols which treated in JS like proper "<" symbol. Razor engine cannot encode them. (Somewhy.)

Comment: @Roman, perhaps I don't understand your issue as the alert is working correctly from the test I just ran?

Comment: Yes, it alerts, and I want this NOT to alert. I want to prevent script in Title text property from running, because it is going from client to DB and later from DB to view.